# mouse event when mouse is getting out of JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouseevent, tablecellrenderer

I use JTable, and have a MouseMotionAdapter listens to the mouse, and coloring the line of the mouse at any given moment.

```
addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override           
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
        {
            JTable aTable =  (JTable)e.getSource();             
            int row = aTable.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
            if(m_cursorRow != row){
                m_cursorRow = row;
                aTable.repaint();
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is, when I move the mouse out of the table, the MouseMotionAdapter is not called, because the mouse is no longer over the JTable...

Is there another event I can use to paint the table again when the mouse is getting out of the JTable borders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there another event I can use to paint the table again when the mouse is getting out of the JTable borders?

You can use the `mouseExited()` event of the `MouseListener`.

Comment: Somehow I missed it. Thanks!